# Writing a method that will be both available in my post view and vote controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following (`Vote` as a polymorphic association with `Post`) :

**votes_controller.rb:**

```
if already_voted?
  @vote = @votable.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
  @vote.destroy
end
```

**posts/_vote_form.html.erb:**

```
<div class="vote-form">      
  <% if @post.votes.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id) %>
    <% if @post.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).polarity == 1 %>
      <%= form_for ([@post, @post.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)]),
                                                           method: :delete,
                                                           remote: true do |f| %>
(etc).
```

I would like to replace `votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)` in both post view and vote controller with something like this:

```
  def vote_by_current_user
    self.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
  end
```

So they become more readeable like this:

`@vote = @votable.vote_by_current_user` or `<% if @post.vote_by_current_user.polarity == 1 %>`

I'm not really sure how to make that method available on both of them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hard to say what your structure is, but I think I would give the user class a has_voted method, both instances above have access to the current_user object, and then maybe you pass in a vote object to search on if that is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

one thing : you should not do anything related to the session in your models (it breaks the MVC pattern), so you're already doing it the right way.

What you can do to improve this is to take it the other way around : start from `current_user`.

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.polarized_vote_for( votable, polarity = 1 )
     votes.where( polarity: polarity ).find_by_votable_id( votable.id )
   end
```

just remember to store the relation returned by the call to avoid multiple queries :

```
 <% if vote = current_user.polarized_vote_for( @post ) %>
   <%= form_for [@post, vote] do |f| %>
     # etc.
```